# Installation on Windows with xampp

Tags: windows, xampp, composer-php, yii2

I am trying to install Yii2 on Windows with no success. I tried several ways.

First tried to install basic and advanced application templates following [official installation instructions](http://www.yiiframework.com/download).

Then I tried with Github. I downloaded [archive](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/framework), unzipped it, placed folder content in htdocs of xampp. When I opened this page http://localhost/my_yii/requirements, it showed "Object not found!" error.

I tried with composer also but failed.

My htdocs path is "D:\php\htdocs" and my php.exe path is "D:\php\php". I think composer installed in this path: "D:\php\php".

Comment: this could be a problem of your .htaccess file, check if it's present. also try accessing http://localhost/my_yii/requirements.php make sure you include the php extension in the url

Comment: Thanks YoelNunez for reply. I included the extension in the url, result is same as previous. I am doing all these in my localhost. There is no .htaccess file. What I have to check in .htaccess file ?? Thanks

Comment: What error prevented you to install it with composer?

Comment: Thanks @arogachev for your reply. I made paste at pastebin. Here is the link  (http://pastebin.com/aKFsE2sR). Thanks

Comment: Try to update composer to the latest version with command `composer self-update` and install again.

Comment: It this doesn't help, try this advice on official forum. http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60340-issue-while-installing-yii-2/